# Script Task C# Error on SFTP Connection

Tags: c#, ssis, sftp

When executing Script Task in SSiS 2008 R2, I am getting the following errors on open SFTP connection line `sFtpConnection.Connect();`:

> SSIS package "avande_auth_response.dtsx" starting.
>   Error: 0x0 at Script Task, SFTP Script Task: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Warning: 0x80019002 at Script Task: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>   Task failed: Script Task
>   Warning: 0x80019002 at avande_auth_response: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>   SSIS package "avande_auth_response.dtsx" finished: Failure.

Here is part of the **C#** script (`SftpDownloadDirctory` variable is used as ReadOnly, and `SftpFileExists` variable is used as ReadWrite):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
.
.
.
 public void Main()
 {
        Try
        {
                // Get the ftp connection from the Connection Managers collection
                ConnectionManager sftpServer = Dts.Connections["avande.SFTP"];

                // Create a FTP connection object and use the credentials of connection manager
                FtpClientConnection sFtpConnection = new FtpClientConnection(sftpServer.AcquireConnection(null));

                // Open the connection
                sFtpConnection.Connect();

                // Set work folder with the value of the variable
                sFtpConnection.SetWorkingDirectory(Dts.Variables["User::SftpDownloadDirctory"].Value.ToString());

                // Create StringArrays for filenames and folders
                // The folderNames aren't used, but, it is mandatory for the next method.
                String[] fileNames;
                String[] folderNames;

                // Get a directory listing and fill the StringArray variables
                sFtpConnection.GetListing(out folderNames, out fileNames);

                if (fileNames != null)
                {
                    // Copy StringArray to ArrayList to fit in Object variable
                    ArrayList fileNamesArray = new ArrayList(fileNames);

                    // Fill ssis object variable
                    Dts.Variables["User::SftpFileList"].Value = fileNamesArray;
                }

                // Close connection
                sFtpConnection.Close();

                // Close Script Task, set result to success
                Dts.Variables["User::SftpFileExists"].Value = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Fire error and set result to failure
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "SFTP Script Task", "Error: " + ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);
                //Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                Dts.Variables["User::SftpFileExists"].Value = false;
            }

        }
 }
```

I have been working on this for a long while now.

Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exception stacktrace?

Comment: what about variable SftpFileList?